# Validation issues

Tags: javascript, validation

I"m trying to get this function to validate against the values of 2 inputs field; namely letters and website but it won't work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

/* Function */

```
function access()
{
if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='man' && ('website').value=='mann')location.href='http://www.google.com'
else if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='woman')location.href='http://www.dynamicdrive.com'
else if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='cat')location.href='http://www.youtube.com'
else if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='dog')location.href='http://www.dailymotion.com'
else alert('Access denied. Try again.')
}
```

/* Form */

```
<div id="cliente">

<form>
<input type='text' class="clientelog" id='website' value="Website"> </input>
<input type='text' class="clientelog" id='letters' value="Code" >
</input>
<input class="checkerbttn" type='button' onclick='access()' value='show me' ></input>
</form>      

</div><!-- End Cliente -->
```

Comment: You're missing `document.getElementById` before website. Other than that, this should work.

Comment: Consider using jQuery. saves you lots of typing: `$('#letters').val()` gives you the value of the form field which you should cache btw and not retrieve **4** times in the same function.

Comment: -1 because it shows absolutely no research effort. Plus the solution provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076336/how-do-i-validate-against-two-possible-values/) is not used. @Dz.slick You're supposed to learn from others, here, not make them do your job.

Comment: `('website').value=='mann'` is a typo?? It should be `document.getElementById('website').value=='mann'`

Comment: Thanks for minusing 1 bro. No body is doing my job, I'm actually learning for my school project. I created the function after some research. All on my Own

Comment: Your question means either you didn't spend enough time looking at your code or you don't know what's a function. You should start learning the basic notions of programming. (I would -1 you again if I could, for calling me bro.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might just be a copy-paste error from when you posted your question, but this line is wrong:

```
if(document.getElementById('letters').value=='man' && ('website').value=='mann') location.href='http://www.google.com'
// ----------------------------------problem is here--^
```

You've got `('website').value` where you should have `document.getElementById('website').value`